# Redirect all traffic from a subdomain on NextJS

Tags: next.js, vercel

I want to redirect all traffic to my pricing page via a subdomain to my homepage. I can't figure out how to add wildcards in the has value.

This syntax does not work:

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  target: 'serverless',
  async redirects() {
    return [
        {
          source: '/pricing',
          has: [
            {
              type: 'host',
              value: '*.*.*',
            },
          ],
          permanent: false,
          destination: 'https://example.com/'
        }
      ]
  },
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey! Two things. 1) You don't need to include target and 2) The `has` support is currently experimental (landing soon).

Comment: Thanks! Will the has object values allow for subdomain wildcards? Aka redirect all subdomain traffic.

Answer (score 2):

Vercel support helped me find the solution. I needed to update my regex in the value.

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  target: 'serverless',
  async redirects() {
    return [
        {
          source: '/pricing',
          has: [
            {
              type: 'host',
              value: '.*\\..*\\..*'
            },
          ],
          permanent: false,
          destination: 'https://example.com/'
        }
      ]
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect the subdomain, you would add the redirect on that project. If you want the contents of the subdomain (e.g. `pricing.example.com`) to show up on a *different* project at `/pricing`, you would use a rewrite.

```js
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/pricing',
        destination: 'https://pricing.example.com'
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: My project has multiple domains associated with it. If a user visits site1.example.com/pricing then redirect to example.com. If a user visits site2.example.com then redirect to example.com. I have so many domains associated with my project I need to add a wildcard value for the subdomain and domain.